# Overlapping imageview between Different layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an imageview at relative layout, but i want to overlap this imageview Between different layouts like this [image]

here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CircularProgressBar" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1268a5" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1268a5" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried using this android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp" in imageview but still i am not able to overlap.

Comment: post your layout code here

Comment: Try using relative or frame layout.It will be much easier

Comment: yes i have posted my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be warned, your layout isn't flexible at all. But here if you really want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".CircularProgressBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="#000000">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1268a5">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1268a5">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```